# Using array in php query?

Tags: php, arrays, mysql-num-rows

i want to obtain number of rows in query using mysql_num_rows.the query itself contains 2 arrays. i want to store the number in array. Here's my code

```
  $antecedent=array();

for($i=0;$i<=$index;$i++){
    if(isset($period[$i])|| isset($gpa[$i]) || isset($antecedent[$i])){
  $queryAntecedent=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE  study_period='$period[$i]' AND ipk='$gpa[$i]'") or die (mysql_error());    

        $antecedent[$i]=mysql_num_rows($queryAntecedent);
        }//endif
}//endfor

print_r ($antecedent);
```

when i only used 1 array inside query, the code works. on the other hand, when i put 2 arrays in it..the code doesn't work(all element in array antecedent contain 0). How to slve this? is it no way using 2 arrays in query? 
Thank you

Comment: It might be that `$period[$i]` and `$gpa[$i]` are never set for the same `$i`. Then you will create a query which does not return anything...

Comment: so, how can i fix it? both have the same number of element derived from the previous process.

Comment: If you want count you are doing it wrong. You may want to use `empty` instead of `isset`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not getting a mysql error when the query runs, then your query is simply returning no rows. Try building the query separately and store it in a variable, so you can view what you've built:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE  study_period='$period[$i]' AND ipk='$gpa[$i]'";
$queryAntecedent=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
echo $sql;
```

Note that you're doing an `||` (or) in your main `if()` statement. This will will let your query go ahead even if only **ONE** of your arrays have values. You'd need to change it to `&&` (and) comparison instead, which requires that **ALL** the arrays have values available.

For instance, if `$gpa[$i]` happens to be empty, then your query becomes

```
 SELECT * ... AND ipk='';
```

which is probably  NOT what you want.

Comment: I've changed it into && but it still doesn't work. do you think this is because i put 2 arrays in a query?

Comment: You can put a million arrays into the query and PHP will do what you tell it to. It all comes down to what the query string looks like after you build it. Garbage in, garbage out. Use my first construct (separate $sql variable) and LOOK at what you're building.

Comment: Thank you, Solved! you are right, it's not the array. ive tried as what you suggested and i found out that array gpa=''. this is only because i typed the array name wrong. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

use `{ }` in the interpolation or concat:

This:

```
"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE  study_period='{$period[$i]}' AND ipk='{$gpa[$i]}'"
```

Or This:

```
"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE  study_period='" . $period[$i] . "' AND ipk='" . $gpa[$i]} . "'"
```

An even better solution is to use [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) or something similar which will allow you to use placeholders and prepared queries. Placeholders help prevent SQL Injection which this query could be vulnerable to. And prepared queries will give you much better performance especially in a loop like you have here.

Comment: If you aren't using PDO you should sanitize those variables to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: i've already tried using bracket and the second way. but, i still couldn't get any value in $antecedent array. maybe i can't put 2 arrays in query :(

Comment: If the count is 0 it's likely that's what your query is returning.

Comment: `{}` notation isn't necessary for interpolating a 1-dimensional array reference in a  string. You'd need them it was multidimensonal, though. `"$arr[1][2]"` would be seen as `{$arr[1]}[2]` by PHP unless you used the `{}` notation.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want count (number of rows) you should do it like this...

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM mytable WHERE study_period = '$period[$i]' AND ipk= '$gpa[$i]'") or die (mysql_error());    
$sql = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
$antecedent[$i]= $sql["count"];
```

Comment: that works in phpmyadmin but that doesn't work when applied on php using two arrays in query. i think that two array can't be put in a query. do you think so?